# A simple CSS/HTML menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I've a proble with a simply CSS/HTML menu!
When I hover in the second voice of menu, the submenu opens over the main menu and not down!
Why?

The  CSS code is here:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar {
    height: 70px;
}
.navbar > li, .navbar > li > a #navbar ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#navbar, #navbar ul {
    .background {
        color:orange;
    }
}
#navbar li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: inline;
}
#navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
#navbar li ul {
    display: none;
}
#navbar li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navbar a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
#navbar li:hover > a {
    background: red;
}
#navbar a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar a:focus #navbar a:hover #navbar a:active {
    background-color: #D76120;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width:130px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    border:1px solid #D76120;
    background: #2D4E6C;
    font-size:.8em;
}
#navbar li li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #D76120;
    width: 130px;
}
.fa {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 70px;
}
.fa-bars {
    color: #3498db;
}
```

the HTML code is

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="pagina1.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><div>Home</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina1.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><div>ciao</div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Roma</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Milano</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Torino</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="pagina4.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><div>ciao</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina5.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><div>ciao</div></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

to understand better you can see the result here:

```
http://www.loasidelweb.netsons.org/proof/ennesimo.php
```

sorry if I posted wrong. 
this is the first time for me.

Comment: Put the code in the question

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code into the body of the question. All questions on Stack Overflow should be answerable based on information contained within the body of the post. Potential answerers shouldn't have to visit an external page to view your code, and future viewers experiencing similar problems will be left in the dark when the links to these live resources break.

Comment: I edit my message. Sorry but it's the first time in this site

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the sub-menu under the list:

Relevant CSS changes:

```
#navbar li
{
   position: relative;  
}

#navbar li:hover ul {
    top:100%;    
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/eLpz6fw8/

I also removed the floating since you are using `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Drop Down Menu</title>
    <style>
        /* main menu css */
        ul li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: red;
        }

        /* drop down css */
        ul li ul {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        ul li:hover ul {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    </style>[Learn From Video][1]
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Company</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Services</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Services 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple cool menu, using `details` element, for those passing by.

```css
.coolmenu {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    height: 2rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Allow larger boxes */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.submenu > p {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.submenu > p:hover {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    background: lightblue;
    color: black
}

.submenu summary {
    background: black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.submenu[open] {
    outline: 5px black solid;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: blue;
}

.submenu[open] summary::after {
    content: '❌';
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="coolmenu">

    <details class="submenu">
      <summary>Configure</summary>
        <p>
          Some stuffs
        </p>
    </details>
    
    <details class="submenu">
      <summary>Options</summary>
        <p>
          More cool
        </p>
        <p>
          stuffs
        </p>
    </details>
    
    <details class="submenu">
      <summary>Tools</summary>
        <p>
          The container can overflow
        </p>
    </details>
</div>
```